# Run some external JS code at runtime in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, runtime

Is it possible to run some external JS code at runtime in Vue?

For example, I have some logic that may be modified by local administrator at runtime without having to reload the whole app, which is stored in database as a chunk of JS code and is accessible through backend via an axios call. So is it possible to include such scripts without pre-compiling them?
To use like this:

```
let params = {...}; //some input props for my stored script

let script = restService.getScript(); //get script code from backend via axios

let result = scriptService.executeScript( script, params ); //execute script with given params
```

I have had similar approach with Java aplication that could execute a stored Groovy script at runtime, would like to implement something like this in my Vue app.

I'm fairly new to frontend JS development, so there might be something obvious that I'm missing.

Answer (score 0):

In your vue application main.js you can define your vue instance like:

```
window.app = new Vue({
      store,
      render: h => h(App)
    });

app.$mount('#app');
```

From external js you can access your Vue instance from `app` object.
If you are using **vuex** you can call **actions** like:

```
app.$store.dispatch('ACTION_NAME', 'Payload');
```